# How can I test exception in completable future?

Tags: java, junit, java-8, junit4, completable-future

I have been converting some code to be asynchronous. The original unit test used the annotation `@Test(expected = MyExcpetion.class)` but I don't think this will work because the exception I want to assert on is wrapped in `java.util.concurrent.ExcutionException` . I did try calling my future like this but my assertion is still failing and I don't love that I had to add in `return null`

```
myApiCall.get(123).exceptionally((ex) -> {
 assertEquals(ex.getCause(),MyCustomException.class)
 return null
}
```

I also tried this flavor but still not working

```
myApiCall.get(123).exceptionally((ex) -> {
 assertThat(ex.getCause())
  .isInstanceOF(MyException.class)
  .hasMessage("expected message etc")
 return null;
}
```

My API just throws exception if it can't find id.  How should I be properly testing this? Can I use that original annotation in anyway?

my api call reaches out to db when run. In this test I am setting up my future to return an error so it doesn't actually try to communicate with anything. the code under test looks like this

```
 public class myApiCall  { 
   public completableFuture get(final String id){
   return myService.getFromDB(id)
    .thenApply( 
       //code here looks at result and if happy path then returns it after 
       //doing some transformation 
      //otherwise it throws exception 
   )
  }
 }
```

in the unit test I force `myService.getFromDB(id)` to return bad data so I can test exception and also keep this a unit test don't reach out to db etc.

Comment: Presumably, your `get` delegates to another thread. Note that JUnit will not wait for completion. If it exits your test method, it will exit the Java process. Instead, `get` on the CF to wait for the result. If there's an exception, unwrap it and assert there (or rethrow it and use your `expected`).

Comment: what is myApiCall here?

Comment: api call just reaches out to db for data . let me update something in the code above so perhaps its clearer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's assume your API throws if called with `0`:

```
public static CompletableFuture<Integer> apiCall(int id) {
  return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    if (id == 0) throw new RuntimeException("Please not 0!!");
    else return id;
  });
}
```

You can test that it works as expected with the following code (I'm using TestNG but I suspect it won't be too difficult to translate into a JUnit test):

```
@Test public void test_ok() throws Exception {
  CompletableFuture<Integer> result = apiCall(1);
  assertEquals(result.get(), (Integer) 1);
}

@Test(expectedExceptions = ExecutionException.class,
      expectedExceptionsMessageRegExp = ".*RuntimeException.*Please not 0!!")
public void test_ex() throws Throwable {
  CompletableFuture<Integer> result = apiCall(0);
  result.get();
}
```

Note that the second test uses the fact that the ExecutionException message will contain the original exception type and message and captures the expectation with a regex. If you can't do that with JUnit, you can call `result.get()` in a try/catch block and call `throw e.getCause();` in the catch block. In other words, something like this:

```
@Test(expectedExceptions = RuntimeException.class,
      expectedExceptionsMessageRegExp = "Please not 0!!")
public void test_ex() throws Throwable {
  CompletableFuture<Integer> result = apiCall(0);
  try {
    result.get();
  } catch (ExecutionException e) {
    throw e.getCause();
  }
}
```

Comment: I had issues with the JUnit flavor so went with the style of your test above wrapping `.get` in try catch and asserting on cause of exception and that worked. When I tried `@Test(expected = MyException.class) ` I had issues but I wonder if I rethrow the exception it might work but I wanted to do deeper assertions on error so was ok with try/catch.

Comment: Doesn't use .get() make it synchronous?

Comment: Yes it does - we need to wait for the result to check that it does what we expect.

Answer (score 3):

You can try also alternative option:

```
import org.hamcrest.core.IsInstanceOf;
import org.junit.rules.ExpectedException;

public class Test() {

    @Rule
    public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();

    @Test
    public void myApiCallTest() {
        thrown.expect(ExcutionException.class);
        thrown.expectCause(IsInstanceOf.instanceOf(MyException.class));
        thrown.expectMessage("the message you expected");
        myApiCall.get("");
    }
}
```

Assuming that:

```
public class myApiCall  { 
    public completableFuture get(final String id) {
        // ...
        throw new ExcutionException(new MyException("the message you expected"))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assume that you have a class and you want to test a method which returns a completable future:

```
  public class A {
    private final Api api;

    public A(Api api) { this.api = api;}

    public CompletableFuture<Void> execute(Integer input) {
       final CompletableFuture<Void> future = api.execute(input)
                .thenApplyAsync(result -> doSomething())
                .exceptionally(ex -> doFailure());
       return future;
    }
 }
```

To test the execution of "doSomething()" then you may use mockito and do the following:

```
     // prepare test
     final Api api = mock(Api.class)
     final A a = new A(api);
     when(api.execute(any(Integer.class)))
          .thenReturn(CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null));

     // execute
     final CompletableFuture<Void> result = a.execute(input);

     // validate
     ...
```

To test "doFailure" do the following:

```
when(api.execute(any(Integer.class))).thenAnswer(answer -> {
     CompletableFuture<Void> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
     future.completeExceptionally(new RuntimeException());
     return future;
});

// execute
final CompletableFuture<Void> result = a.execute(input);

// validate
assertTrue(result.isCompletedExceptionally());
```

Answer (score 1):

that is easy thing doing in junit-4. Are you remember the `@RunWith` annotation? Yes, write your own `TestRunner` to intercept the exception before the junit expected exception processor is invoked, for example:

```
public class ConcurrentRunner extends BlockJUnit4ClassRunner {

    public ConcurrentRunner(Class<?> klass) throws InitializationError {
        super(klass);
    }


    @Override
    protected Statement possiblyExpectingExceptions(FrameworkMethod method, 
                                                    Object test,
                                                    Statement next) {
        return super.possiblyExpectingExceptions(
               method, test, throwingActualException(next)
        );
    }

    private Statement throwingActualException(Statement next) {
        return new Statement() {
            @Override
            public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
                try {
                    next.evaluate();
                } catch (ExecutionException | CompletionException source) {
                    throw theActualExceptionOf(source);
                }
            }

            private Throwable theActualExceptionOf(Exception source) {
                return source.getCause() != null ? source.getCause() : source;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

just annotated with `@RunWith(ConcurrentRunner.class)` on the test, you needn't change your test code at all. for example:

```
@RunWith(ConcurrentRunner.class)
public class ConcurrentExpectedExceptionTest {

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void caughtTheActualException() throws Throwable {
        myApiCall().join();
    }

    private CompletableFuture<Object> myApiCall() {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `Mockito.when(..).thenReturn(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(..))` worked for me. Inside the supply I put a short `Thread.sleep()` and then throw my test exception