# How to write test for Execution Exception

Tags: java

I have the following method. It works fine and able to test the remaining parts of the code. But how can I test / simulate that that catch block which catches ExecutionException? I want to land in that catch block. I am using Mockito to mock other parts but its not like I can mock that try block in this instance, or can I?

```
private static ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

public Detail create(String num){

    return new Detail(){

        private final Future<String> number = executor.submit(() -> someAutowiredClass.method(num));

        @Override
        public String getNumber() {
            try {
                return this.number.get();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new CustomException();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                throw new CustomException2();
                // I want to land inside here for my test. How do I do that? 
            }
        }
    };
}
```

This is how I have written test for the interrupted portion currently.

```
@Test
public void myTest() {
    String num  = "123";
    String number = "456";
    when(someAutowiredClass.method(num)).thenReturn(456);

    Detail detail = myClass.create(num);
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();

    try {
        assertEquals(number, detail.getNumber());
    }catch (CustomException e){
        // some assertions.
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you do in `ExecutionException` catch block? Do you throw exception or return some constant value?

Comment: @MichałZiober I throw another Custom Exception.

Comment: In that case take a look at [How can I test exception in completable future?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44633885/how-can-i-test-exception-in-completable-future)

Comment: you should mock the "number" future since your function is working with the future. Alternatively you can both the executor and the future to test both the lambda and the getter

Comment: @MichałZiober this is Future, but sure will have a look at it, thanks.